# enabled fielddata on text field in ElasticSearch but aggregation is not working

Tags: elasticsearch

According to the documentation you can run ElasticSearch aggregations on fields that are type **keyword** or not a text field or which have **fielddata** set to true in the index mapping.

I am trying to count **city_names** in an nginx log. It works fine with the int field **result**.  But it does not work with the field city_name even when I updated the index mapping for that to put **fielddata=true**. The should have been not required as it was of type **keyword**.

To say it does not work means that:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "cities" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [ ]
    }
  }
```

Here is the field mapping:

```
"city_name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fielddata" : true
        },
```

And here is the aggression query:

```
curl -XGET --user $pwd --header 'Content-Type: application/json'  https://58571402f5464923883e7be42a037917.eu-central-1.aws.cloud.es.io:9243/logstash/_search?pretty -d '{
      "aggs" : {
        "cities": {
           "terms" : { "field": "city_name"}
        }
    }
}'
```

Comment: Try adding fielddata_frequency_filter in your mapping. and in elastic it takes a little time to reindex fragments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't get any error when executing your search it seems that is more like a problem with the data. Are you sure you have, at least, one document with the field **city_name** filled?

I tried to reproduce your issue with ElasticSearch 6.6.2.

- I created an index

  ```
  PUT cities
  {
    "mappings": {
      "city": {
        "dynamic": "true",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "city_name": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- I added one document without the city_name

  ```
  PUT cities/city/1
  {
    "id": "1"
  }
  ```

When i performed the search:

```
GET cities/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "cities": {
       "terms" : { "field": "city_name"}
    }
  }
}
```

I got no buckets in the **cities** aggregation. But when I added one document with the city name filled:

```
PUT cities/city/2
{
  "id": "2",
  "city_name": "London"
}
```

I got the expected result:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 2,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "cities",
        "_type" : "city",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "2",
          "city_name" : "london"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "cities",
        "_type" : "city",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "aggregations" : {
    "cities" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "london",
          "doc_count" : 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It has data.  I am using Elastic Cloud, which is version 7.x. And like I said it works with numeric fields.  Just not text.

Comment: Just tried the same example in ElasticSearch 7.2.0 and it worked. Can you share your index schema?

Comment: I was looking into the query results and the index mapping and, according with the first 10 results, the city_name is only in the geoip object (not filled in the root object). I did the same test I documented (now with ES 7.2.0) and the aggregation worked when I added a document with the city_name defined in the root object. If you want to use the city_name defined in the geoip object, you should change you search request to aggregate the results by the **geoip.city_name** field

Comment: curl -XPUT /logstash/_mapping -d '{ 
  "properties": {
    "geoip.city_name": {
      "type":     "text",
      "fielddata": true
    }
  }
}'
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"remote_transport_exception","reason":"[instance-0000000001][172.17.0.15:19022][indices:admin/mapping/put]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Mapper for [geoip.city_name] conflicts with existing mapping:\n[mapper [geoip.city_name] has different [norms] values, cannot change from disable to enabled]"

Comment: To aggregate by the city_name in the geoip object use: 'GET logstash-2019.06.19-000001/_search
{
  "aggs": {
    "saNAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "geoip.city_name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}'

Comment: Very good Jorge.  How did you figure that out?  Anyway it's working.

Comment: Looking at your mapping I saw that **geoip.city_name** doesn't have the field data enabled but has the **keyword** field which allows you to perform aggregations on it.